# Why isn't count returning the correct number of elements in a Doctrine Collection?

Tags: php, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm, persistence

I have the following code:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            if($groupType == 'existing'){
                $urlGroup = $em->getRepository('UrlBuilderBundle:UrlGroup')->find($groupId);
            }elseif($groupType == 'new'){
                $urlGroup   = new UrlGroup();
                $groupName  = $submittedData['groupName'];
                $urlGroup->setName($groupName);
                $em->persist($urlGroup);
            }

            $url = new Url();
            $url->setName($name);
            $url->setAuthorUser($authorUser);
            $url->setUrl($generatedUrl);
            $url->setUrlGroup($urlGroup);

            $em->persist($url);
            $em->flush();

            $urlGroupName = $urlGroup->getName();
            $urlCount = count($urlGroup->getUrls());
```

When a new UrlGroup is created, the last line (count of child URL objects) **always returns zero even when a URL has been added for the given UrlGroup**. This code is used in an AJAX call.

Upon page refresh count() returns the correct number.

Appreciate it if anyone can help shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because fact that you do `$em->flush()` means that database operation is performed but it does not mean that your `$urlGroup` object is refreshed - php still has its state before `flush` has been performed, meaning with 0 `urls`.

Try to call:

```
$em->refresh($urlGroup)
```

right after `$em->flush`. This will refresh `$urlGroup` with info from database

Answer (score 0):

I think that accepted answer is a bit misleading - yes, you will refresh the object with it's collection, but in my opinion this is a workaround. What generally `flush` gives are the identifiers (id's) to your model.

You are calling `$url->setUrlGroup($urlGroup);` in the `owning` side, but not updating the `inverse` side. What needs to be done in `setUrlGroup` method in `Url` class:

```
public function setUrlGroup($group)
{
    $this->urlGroup = $group;
    $group->addUrl($this);
}
```

And respectfully in `UrlGroup` class:

```
public function addUrl($url)
{
    if (!$this->$urls->contains($url) {
        $this->$urls->add($url);
    }
}
```

Supposedly `$urls` above is instance of `ArrayCollection`.

This fixes the relation on the `inverse` side of your mapping. I would strongly recommend doing this way.